# Polar to rectangular and back

Tags: c, graphics, polar-coordinates

I'm a little stuck. I'm trying to achieve a basic polar to rectangular conversion to match that of Photoshop's but I'm not getting the same results.

Converting from rectangular to polar matches Photoshop's but going from polar back to rectangular does not.

You can see in this image the differences between Photoshop's and mine:
[image: Polar Conversion]

```
float a, b, ang, dist;
int px, py;
const PI=3.141592653589793;

// Convert from cartesian to polar
for (y=y_start; y<y_end; ++y)
{
    for (x=x_start; x<x_end; ++x)
    {
        a = (float)(x-X/2);
        b = (float)(y-Y/2);

        dist = (sqr(a*a + b*b)*2.0);

        ang = atan2(b,-a)*(58);
        ang = fmod(ang + 450.0,360.0);

        px = (int)(ang*X/360.0);
        py = (int)(dist);

        pset(x, y, 0, src(px,py,0));
        pset(x, y, 1, src(px,py,1));
        pset(x, y, 2, src(px,py,2));
    }
}

// Convert back to cartesian
for (y=y_start; y<y_end; ++y)
{
    for (x=x_start; x<x_end; ++x)
    {

        ang = ((float)x/X)*PI*2.0;

        dist = (float)y*0.5;

        px = (int)(cos(ang)*dist)+X/2;
        py = (int)(sin(ang)*dist)+Y/2;

        pset(x, y, 0, pget(px,py,0));
        pset(x, y, 1, pget(px,py,1));
        pset(x, y, 2, pget(px,py,2));
    }
}
```

This is my code. I'm sure I've messed something up in the polar to cartesian. The language is based off C.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: You should format your code properly so it's more readable.

Comment: What are big X and Y? Why are you doing decimal arithmetic in `float` rather than `double`?  What are the magic numbers 58 and 450.0, i.e., where did they come from?

Comment: Yes, sorry it's not very clear. Big X is screen Width, big Y is screen height. Without 58, the polar conversion does not wrap properly. These were code snippets I found so I am also trying to clean them up and understand them better.

Comment: Just cleaned up and formatted the code a bit more.

Comment: 58 ~= 180.0 / PI.  Clearly you don't *really* want to convert to degrees and then convert back to radians again.

Comment: Just a minor comment: Use ```90.0``` rather than ```450.0```. It doesn't change the result, but is more readable (90 degrees rotation).

Comment: So any ideas why the color bar order doesn't match up to Photoshop's result, as well as what is causing the circle in the lower part?

Comment: @HansPassant's comment hits it right on the head. You should use `180.0 / PI` instead of `58.0`.

Comment: Because your polar-to-cartesian function is not the inverse of your cartesian-to-polar function. You need to bring your angle back to `[-π/2,π/2]` range, and invert your `x` value back.

Comment: Hi n.m. Thanks for your reply. Could you explain in more detail using example code? Thanks

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly your conversion is without knowing X, Y and the range of x and y. I cannot match the picture with the formula. Can you show how e.g the red vertical strip gets converted to the red sector?

Comment: Hi n.m. Well, x and y are the current pixels being processed, in rows and columns. Big X and big Y are the image widths & heights. So if I am working on a 255x255 image (the vertical strip image), the big X & Y = 255 and the x = 0 to 255, y = 0 to 255. The second image is the cartesian to polar and the third image is the polar back to cartesian. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: This is the inverse conversion of angle:
ang = (((x * 360.0 / X) - 90.0) * PI / 360.0);
px = - (int)(cos(ang)*dist) + X/2;

Comment: The explicit 90-degree phase shift can be avoided by swapping the arguments to `atan2()` and negating one.  I think `atan2(-a, -b)` ends up being the right sense and phase.  Of course, the back conversion needs then to be adjusted, too.

Comment: Also, for both speed and precision it is better to do as little floating-point arithmetic as possible.  To that end, work directly in radians instead of converting to degrees (otherwise, the scale factor just ends up being divided back out anyway).

Comment: @n.m.  Concerning "need to bring your angle back to `[-π/2,π/2]` range".   `atan2()` returns  `[-π,π]`.  Is that the range you meant?

Comment: @chux yes, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your polar-to-cartesian transformation:

- The axes of the coordinate system you use to define angles are pointing right (x) and down (y) while you used a coordinate system with upwards- (x) and left-pointing (y) axes for your cartesian-to-polar transformation. The code to convert the angle to cartesian should be (I've added a bit of rounding)

  ```
  px = round(-sin(ang)*dist + X/2.)
  py = round(-cos(ang)*dist + Y/2.)
  ```

  With that code you move from red to green to blue instead of from gray to blue to green in the final picture when increasing the x coordinate there.
- Assuming that `pget` and `pset` operate on the same bitmap, you're overwriting your source image. The loop construct takes you outward along concentric circles around the center of the source image while filling the target line by line, top to bottom. at some point the circles and the lines start to overlap and you start reading the data you modified earlier (happens at the apex of the parabola-like shape). It gets even more convoluted because at some point you start reading the transform of that modified data, so that it is effectively transformed again (I guess that causes the irregular triangular region on the right).